# Why won't my program find/open my .csv file

Tags: python

I'm trying to get my program to read my .csv file and when I run it, it says there is no such file. I converted an excel file of 10000 random numbers that range from 1,100 and I'm trying to run those numbers through my code. Am I getting this error from my .csv file or is it an error from my code?

```
import csv
import math
import statistics

filename = "data5.csv"
# create array
array = []
def calcstdDev(data):
    n = len(data)
    mean = sum(data) / n
    var = sum((x - mean)**2 for x in data) / n
    std_dev = var ** 0.5
    return std_dev

def ProcessData(data):
    print("\nThe Mean is: %.4f \n" % (statistics.mean(data)))
    print("\nThe Min is: %d \n" % (min(data)))
    print("\nThe Max is: %d \n" % (max(data)))
    print("\nThe Mode is: %d \n" % (statistics.mode(data)))
    print("\nThe StandDev: %.4f \n" % (statistics.stdev(data)))
    print("\nMy StandDev: %.4f \n" % (calcstdDev(data)))

def main():
    # reading csv file
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        # creating a csv reader object
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        # extracting each data row one by one
        for row in csvreader:
            value = int(row[0])     # get first element from line in file, convert to int
            array.append(value)     # add value to array
    # print contents of array
    print("\n array\n")
    print(array)
    ProcessData(array)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # execute only if run as a script
    main()
```

Comment: is your file "data5.csv" in the same directory as your python script?

Comment: How do you run this code and from which directory? Where is the CSV file located?

Comment: What error are you getting?  Please post the complete error report starting with traceback. You can surround the report with 3` before and 3` after to properly format the output.

Comment: This is the error I am getting:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\suzie\Downloads\dataread2.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\suzie\Downloads\dataread2.py", line 31, in main    
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data5.csv'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll not fix your problem, but I'll tell you how you can fix all problems of this sort by yourself in the future.

Download [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and add a filter for `python.exe`, like so:

[image: Process Monitor configuration]

Then start recording and look for `data5.csv` and see in which directory it looks for that file.

[image: Find dialog of Process Monitor]

If the file is not found, it will be displayed with the result "Name not found":

[image: Result]

Understand what a working directory is. The CSV file will be searched in the working directory if you didn't provide a full path.

You can also output the working directory from your Python code:

```py
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

It should be the same directory as shown in Process Monitor.

If you're running the program from the commend line, you can do like this:

```
X:\> cd /d X:\wherever\the\csv\is\
X:\wherever\the\csv\is\> "X:\full\path\to\python3.exe" "X:\projects\python\mypython.py"
```

That way the working directory is `X:\wherever\the\csv\is\` and it will find the CSV file.

Don't `cd` where `python3.exe` is. Don't `cd` where `mypython.py` is.

Comment: Thank you for the quick tutorial for using ProcessMonitor to address this kind of issue!  I have processmonitor, but never had opportunity to really learn it.   A bit of overkill for the OP's question, IMO but this answer belongs in everyone's toolbox!  (Another tool I might uses is void tools `Everything` to find out where the file is...)

Comment: @RufusVS: thanks for the kind words. I use Process Monitor almost every week to fix all sorts of issues and find other interesting stuff.